# Is there a way to simplify this loop? new to python

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop

```
E = [('c', 1), ('a', 1), ('t', 2), ('l', 1), ('e', 1)]

def check_freq(x):
    decoded_string = ''
    for element in x:
        decoded_string += int(element[1]) * element[0]
    print(decoded_string)
check_freq(E)
```

The function takes an encoded string and returns the decoded version in this case we get 'cattle', I just wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this or some tips that can help me achieve better efficiency

Comment: What measures of efficiency are you concerned with?

Comment: For all performance question, always answer the following: How fast is your code now? How fast does it need to become? What machine are you testing this on (detailed hardware specs: CPU, RAM, Disk)? Which version and architecture of Python? Generally, C++ is probably faster. So if you're worried about performance, learn C++ instead.

Comment: The function is called "check_freq". What is it checking?

Comment: Why does the encoded value contain `('t', 1), ('t', 1)` and not `('t', 2)`?

Comment: "Optimize my working code" is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just expect your code to be shorter like this:

```py
E = [('c', 1), ('a', 1), ('t', 1), ('t', 1), ('l', 1), ('e', 1)]


def check_freq(lst):
    return ''.join([tpl[1] * tpl[0] for tpl in lst])
    
print(check_freq(E))
```

Comment: Thanks this solution is pretty clean!

Comment: You could skip those open/closing brackets like this - ```return ''.join(tpl[1] * tpl[0] for tpl in lst)```

Answer (score 0):

With some imports you could do this:

```
from operator import mul
from itertools import starmap

check_freq = lambda x: "".join(starmap(mul, x))

E = [('c', 1), ('a', 1), ('t', 1), ('t', 1), ('l', 1), ('e', 1)]
print(check_freq(E))  # cattle
```